# Search-Mailbox cmdlet in Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet

I sent a email from administrator to a user usertest4 with title and body: 'aaaaaaa'.

Waiting 5 minutes then i execute this script:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity 'usertest4' -SearchQuery {(From:"*admin*" AND Body:"*h*" AND Received<= "05/16/2021 05:16")} -EstimateResultOnly -Confirm:$False -Force:$true
```

Result return:

```
RunspaceId       : 1e48d0dd-77b1-4dcd-9178-257fc511832c
TargetMailbox    :
Success          : True
TargetFolder     :
ResultItemsCount : 0
ResultItemsSize  : 0 B (0 bytes)
```

When i'm changed EstimateResultOnly to DeleteContent, it delete this email in usertest4's mailbox then return result:

```
RunspaceId       : 1e48d0dd-77b1-4dcd-9178-257fc511832c
TargetMailbox    :
Success          : True
TargetFolder     :
ResultItemsCount : 1
ResultItemsSize  : 6.799 KB (6,962 bytes)
```

Something wrong here?

Why EstimateResultOnly return 0 but DeleteContent return 1?

Comment: did it ever work?